# Avoid doctrine postloadEvent if unnecessary

Tags: symfony, event-handling, doctrine, lazy-loading, sonata-admin

For an blog entry entity I am loading data from an api via the doctrine postloadEvent. For this i created a listener service with an postloadMethod in it.

```
public function postLoad(BlogEntry $blogEntry)
{
    $blogentry->setName($apiClient->getName($blogEntry->getId()))
    $blogentry->setContent($apiClient->getContent($blogEntry->getId()))
    ...
}
```

This means, there is already a local repository with blog entries. These blogentries are connected to a blog. If i now only want to count the blogentries for each blog, i would implement a getBlogEntryCount() method on the BlogEntry entity and call it.

$blog->getBlogEntryCount();

The problem now is, that the postLoad event is triggered unnecessary, even if i need no data from the api.

How can i avoid this behaviour in doctrine/symfony/sonata admin? Is there  mechanism like "lazy loading" for doctrine entities?

**Update to Jose M. González Solution**

To get only the count of the collection, the extra_lazy loading solution will do it.
For getting local information without triggering the api call i used the said repository function. To get this information working in list view in sonata admin, i created a non-doctrine-related array field "blogEntriesSimple" in my Blog Entity next to my "blogEntries" (which is normally holding the complete entity) field. 
I attached an entitylistener with postLoad function to the Blog Entity, which is filling up my blogEntriesSimple array with the information from my custom repository function.
Thats it.

I think this solution is a bit hacky, but until no cleaner solution is available, this will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you can achieve this with the [extra lazy associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) that permit that you count your related entities without hydrating it

**Edited**

Also you can do a DQL query that only hidrate a partial view of your entity and it can be used to count the rows and access to your properties, for example:

```
select be.id,be.title from AppBundle\Entity\BlogEntry be
```

This query must not trigger the postLoad event

I hope this can help you

Comment: This is a nice idea and helps me for some situations i only need a count ... do you know if this is also possible not just for a count on the collection, but also for getting just a property which is in the database? Assume i want to get only the id's of the blogentries without firing the postLoad Event ...

Comment: According with the Doctrine documentation you can do this methods without trigger a full load: Collection#contains($entity), Collection#containsKey($key), Collection#count(), Collection#get($key),Collection#slice($offset, $length = null). With this in mind i think that the answer is no, if you try to fetch a property you will trigger the entity load.
In the other hand i think that you can do a query in the BlogEntries repository that return only the proporties that you need, this possibility you to count the rows and get the properties that matters to you, but this is only and idea.

Comment: And to make a dql query in the repository will not trigger a postLoad event? Or how you think, should the needed properties have to be loaded?

Comment: Yes, this could work ... but now i have the problem that i cant manipulate the ListMapper in sonata admin to attach the BlogEntries for each Blog-Entity ... the ListMapper does not support callback functions or something else. Only adding a new field to the entity will display new data ... but that will trigger the postloadEvent ... its really annoying ... i turn in a circle ... :/

Comment: I got it working with sonata admin. A bit hacky, but it works! Many thanks for your help and patience :)

Comment: Not at all, a pleasure